# permission denied writing file jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x

when I try to write a file from servlet I receive file not found exception caused by permission denied.

I have to write some files uploaded by users, outside of my .ear

I'm working with jboss 7 started in standalone mode from eclipse.

are there solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, where exactly are you writing the file? Web applications usually only write files to very specific directories, usually configured by the system administrator.

Comment: unfortunately I have to develop under Windows 8 and I'd need to save the files in a folder under c :/

I remember that in the past I didn't have permission problems with jboss.

Comment: Hmmm, the "permission denied" is probably from the operating system. Try to see if you can get a simple Java program to write a file under the directory you want. If the OS gives an error, it's very likely not JBoss fault.

Comment: yes, I think so too ... and in fact you're right, it was a permissions problem that I solved on windows 8.
I'm sorry.

I had thought that he could be a jboss security policy.

thanks

Comment: cool, glad you worked that out.